# How to compare Text property of Text Box with ListView items in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing an **UWP** app. In it I have a **MainPage**. Inside **MainPage** there is  `splitview` and a **frame** inside `splitview.content`. I navigate through this **frame** to various pages. In one page I have a **Grid**. In **Grid** I have three `rows`. The middle row have `ListView`. Here the problem arise. the `ListView` was working fine. But suddenly due to unknown reasons the margin between the items become very long. First two `items` are OK. They are visible on screen. But third one and onwards all `items` are below with very large margin. Even changing the margin of `ListView` and `ListViewItems` doesn't change anything. The `ListView` is bound with `Observable collection`. The XAML code is:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="AccountsList"   ItemsSource="{x:Bind accounts}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Account">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

The cause of the problem is somewhere in `code behind`. The user write text in `textbox` and click `Add Button`. I am trying to access the `text` from each `ListViewitem` or databound property of `ObservableCollection` and compare it with the `Text` provided by user for adding to `ObservableCollection`. If the `text` is `same` the process is aborted otherwise the item is added to `ObservableCollection`. The c# code is

```
if (AccountsList.Items.Any())
        {
            string[] newName =AccountsList.Items.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();
            int itemCount = newName.Count();
            CountTextBlock.Text = itemCount.ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j <= itemCount; j++)
                foreach(var item in newName )
                if (NameTextBox.Text.ToString() == item)
                {
                    await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Name already added- Write a new name in the Text box to Add").ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {

                    accounts.Add(new Account { Name = NameTextBox.Text });
                    NameTextBox.Text = "";
                }
        }
        else
        {

            accounts.Add(new Account { Name = NameTextBox.Text });
            NameTextBox.Text = "";
        }
```

Using `CountTextBlock` for test purpose.The `CountTextBlock.Text` is showing **1 **  when `second item` added. **3 ** when `third item` added and **15 ** when `fourth item` added.**255** when `fifth item` added. **Bottom margin** increases with every new `addition`. When I tried to add `sixth item` the **"OutOfMemoryException"** was thrown. I simply want to compare the **listView items** or **Collection** to which the **ListView** is **DataBounded** with user input in **textbox** to avoid **duplication**.

Comment: What relations are between AccountList and accounts. They should be the same? and this method is when the selectionchanged event is fired?

Comment: AccountsList is the name of ListView and accounts is the ObservableCollection. The  ListView is Data bounded with accounts. This method is called when the user click Add button after entering text in the TextBox. I want to add the item only if it is not duplicate of an existing ListView item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to find out the answer from some another resource. The correct code block is:

```
 if (AccountsList.Items.Any())
                {
                    int count = AccountsList.Items.Count();
                    int check = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (NameTextBox.Text == (AccountsList.Items[i] as Account).Name)
                        {
                            await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Name already added- Write a new name in the Text box to Add").ShowAsync();
                            break;
                        }
                        check += 1;
                        if (check == count)
                            accounts.Add(new Account { Name = NameTextBox.Text });
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    accounts.Add(new Account { Name = NameTextBox.Text });

                }
                NameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

I was having problem with comparing `TextBox.Text` with `ListView.Items`. The below code slove that problem

```
if (NameTextBox.Text == (AccountsList.Items[i] as Account).Name)
```

Now I can compare both values and enter new value only when it is unique to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try with this combinations.

#### ListViewItemPresenter

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemPresenterStyle" TargetType="ListViewItemPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentMargin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
```

#### ListViewItem

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
                                           CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
                                           ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                           CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
                                           DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                           DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                           FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
                                           Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" PointerOverBackgroundMargin="1"
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           PointerOverBackground="Transparent"
                                           ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="Transparent"
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                                           SelectedForeground="Transparent"
                                           SelectedPointerOverBackground="Transparent"
                                           SelectedBorderThickness="0"
                                           SelectedBackground="Transparent"
                                           Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemPresenterStyle}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

#### ListView control

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}"></ListView>
```

As you see, you can set the margins in both styles, Presenter and item. Try and tell me if this solve the problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is with c# code behind. Otherwise the listview is working fine. Please look at updated question